Laravel 7x fix race conditions - table cache_locks is empty
I'm trying to fix race conditions by applying Atomic Locks, like stated in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache
My environment file is configured to use the database driver and I have both cache and cache_locks table migrated.
I can see some contents being written in the cache table but the cache_locks is always empty.
This is my code logic to fix race conditions:
$lock = Cache::lock("{$myUniqueId}_lock", 5);

try 
{
    $lock->block(5);

    // Perform some database operation
    \DB::statement("UPDATE my_table SET some_column = {$some_data}");
} 
catch (LockTimeoutException $e) 
{
    throw new \Exception('Error with atomic locks');
} 
finally 
{
    $lock->release();
}

While performing a stress test on postman with 20 virtual users:

I get the MySQL error Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '....' for key '....', meaning the locks are not being performed correctly
The table cache_locks is always empty, it doesn't hold any value, I keep refreshing but I don't see anything being written there
The LockTimeoutException is never thrown

What am I missing?

Assuming $myUniqueId is not actually unique and always the same for all incoming requests (otherwise they wouldn't be competing on the same lock) then UPDATE my_table SET some_column = {$some_data} will write $some_data once it acquires the lock. If another process acquired the lock and then wrote the data already then you'd see the duplicate entry error anyway because the waiting process will still try to perform the update after the other process finished. The lock wouldn't work in this case unless there's something I am missing.

@apokryfos you're absolutely right. Now that I think about it, it makes sense that the duplicated entry error still shows up, because the $myUniqueId is actually similar to the 20 virtual users (they all share the same API token).  So maybe I need to apply the lock way earlier in the code (?).

If you do have the database constraints then I would argue you don't actually need a lock. Once one request puts the database entry in, let the rest of the requests just fail. Maybe catch the 1062 error and ignore it if you don't want it to show up in your logs.

@apokryfos Yes exactly and since I'm already using DB::transaction as a middleware, it will work nicely and the data won't be inserted into DB in case of error.
